# MAC Address Node JS - How to parse correct one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking

I am working with Node to get the MAC address of local machines. It is pretty simple to get the network interface data with `os.networkInterfaces()` and there are a couple packages that parse this a little and returned refined results. I checked out `node-macaddress` and `getmac`, but essentially all of the above run me into the same problem.

I had recently installed VirtualBox as part of a local development environment and it seems to have activated two network adapters to communicate with the main system and internet I presume. I am not an expert in virtualization. Anyways, the MAC addresses for both of these come up in the results. I can always filter out the VirtualBox adapters but I would image there are other situations similar to this that I may run into.

I would like a way to uniquely identify the computer that my code is running on. How can I account for these network adapters that aren't what I am looking for?

Comment: It's always possible for there to be more than one network adapter, VirtualBox or not.